# section_multiplane from Trimesh in Rust

Tags: rust, geospatial, mesh, geo, trimesh

Is there the equivalent of `mesh.section_multiplane` from the trimesh Python library in Rust?

I tried using [`GenericTrimesh.intersection_with_local_plane`](https://docs.rs/parry3d/latest/parry3d/shape/struct.GenericTriMesh.html#method.intersection_with_local_plane) from `parry3d` but it is not working properly, meaning the polylines I got were superimposed and didn't form polygons.